# Getting undefined method `created_at'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why is this so? Is there any chance I can get created date of my object?

**index.html.erb**

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', article_date(article) %></td>
```

**articles_helper.rb**

```
module ArticlesHelper
  def article_date(article)
    published_at = article.created_at
    options = {
      year: published_at.strftime('%Y'),
      month: published_at.strftime('%m'),
      day: published_at.strftime('%d'),
      id: article.id
    }
    article_date(options)
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Is your object saved? 'created_at' do should return the date at when the object was created

Comment: @CristianoAlencar It is saved.

Comment: What do you mean to return from the method `article_date`? Right now, you're returning a recursive call to `article_date` itself.  If you weren't hitting this error, you'd be entering an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your last image you're passing in a hash to your article_date function. You should be passing an Article object so that you'd have 'created_at' method.